# Limit SeekBar Progress Within 20<Range<5000 to one popup

Tags: android

My SeekBar thumb must move within range 20 to 5000.

I need to prevent the thumb to move below 20. when this amount is reached, a toast message appear telling the user "minimum value reached".

However when i slide to minimum value and forced slide on limit, that is multiple slide towards 20, several popup appears onscreen. How can i limit to only one popup on screen on multiple slide towards minimum or maximum value.

Here is my .setOnSeekBarChanged listener :

```
sbMensualite.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progress = progress / 1;
                progress = progress * 1;

                if (progress<20){
                    progress=20;
                }

                else {}


                if (duree_int>=Constant.DUREE_MAX_VALUE){

                    Toast.message="durée maximum atteinte";
                    m.startActivity(new Intent(m, Toast.class));

                }else if (duree_int<=Constant.DUREE_MIN_VALUE){

                    Toast.message="durée minimum atteinte";
                    m.startActivity(new Intent(m, Toast.class));

                }else {

                    //set progress duree android
                    sbDDuree.setProgress(duree_int);

                    //set amount of month for duree
                    txDDure.setText(Util.doubleNoDp(duree));
                }


                //set mensualite amount
                txMensualite.setText(Util.decimalFormat(progress));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

        });
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I need to prevent the thumb to move below 20. when this amount is reached, a toast message appear telling the user "minimum value reached".*

First. Make the range of your slider be 0-4980. And every time you read the value add +20. If you want to set the value programmatically from a variable add -20.

Second, you really should NOT show a toast to tell that the minimum value was reached, because, using the method described in the previous paragraph, this will be obvious.

EDIT:
Would limiting the `duree_int` variable work for you???

```
   if (duree_int>Constant.DUREE_MAX_VALUE){
        duree_int = Constant.DUREE_MAX_VALUE;
        Toast.message="durée maximum atteinte";
        m.startActivity(new Intent(m, Toast.class));

    }else if (duree_int<Constant.DUREE_MIN_VALUE){
        duree_int = Constant.DUREE_MIN_VALUE;
        Toast.message="durée minimum atteinte";
        m.startActivity(new Intent(m, Toast.class));

    }else {
```

Comment: lets say initial range is 0 to 10000 then, between range 20 to 5000 show a toast etc. do you have my point ? i need to satisfy client demand, client rule.

Comment: Thanks you merlevede i found a solution and it works now

Answer (score 0):

To cancel your existing toast and show a new one after, try this:

```
Toast myToast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

sbMensualite.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                progress = progress / 1;
                progress = progress * 1;

                if (progress<20){
                    progress=20;
                }

                if (duree_int>=Constant.DUREE_MAX_VALUE){
                    myToast.cancel();   //hide existing toast
                    myToast.setText("durée maximum atteinte");
                    myToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGHT_SHORT);
                    myToast.show();

                }else if (duree_int<=Constant.DUREE_MIN_VALUE){
                    myToast.cancel();   //hide existing toast
                    myToast.setText("durée minimum atteinte");
                    myToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGHT_SHORT);
                    myToast.show();

                }else {

                    //set progress duree android
                    sbDDuree.setProgress(duree_int);

                    //set amount of month for duree
                    txDDure.setText(Util.doubleNoDp(duree));
                }


                //set mensualite amount
                txMensualite.setText(Util.decimalFormat(progress));

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

        });
```